# Responsive LI and UL on different resolution not properly aligned

Tags: php, html, css, responsive-design

I've been doing e-commerce CMS for three months now and I just find out about this problem. I'm usually a back-end developer working with PHP and this is not my "bright side".

On my resolution `1440x900` the page is loading fine (3 columns * X-No. of rows):
[image]

The problem is happening on smaller (block) resolution, for example, you can see at the `1063x1280`.
[image]

Here is the current code (The  tag is broken periodically after three articles):

```
<div class="category-products">
    <div class="col-3-grid">

        <ul class="products-grid clearfix" style="margin-right: 5px; margin-left: 20px;">


            <li class="item last" style="min-height: 339px; margin-right: 15px;">
                <a id="product-image-42321" href="proizvod/suspe-22-41471-ger" title="naziv" > 
                    <!-- GLAVNA SLIKA -->
                    <img src="http://------------/images/artikli/22-41471.jpg" width="220px" alt="SUSPENSION MULTI-PLIER" /><br />
                </a>
                <ul class="swatches clearfix">
                    <a href="proizvod/suspe-22-41471-ger" title="SUSPENSION MULTI-PLIER">
                        <li id="swatch-79452" class="swatch product-104101"><img style="display: inline-block; border: 1px solid #B6B6B6; padding: 2px; margin-bottom: 0px !important;" src="images/amconf/crna.jpg" > </img></li>         
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="price-box">
                <span class="label" id="configurable-price-from-42321">
                    <span class="configurable-price-from-label">
                    </span>
                </span>


                <div class="product-name"><a id="product-name-140981" href="proizvod/suspe-22-41471-ger">SUSPENSION MULTI-PLIER</a></div>

                <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-42321">
                    <span class="price">88,00<sup>KM</sup>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>

            <div class="actions">
            </div>

        </li>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.category-products .item {
  border: 1px solid #ececec;
  margin-top: 17px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.1s linear;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.1s linear;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.1s linear;
  transition: border-color 0.1s linear;
}
.category-products .item:hover {
  border-color: #f89c29;
}
.category-products .products-list .product-name {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.category-products .products-list .actions {
  float: right;
  font: 24px/24px "UnitedItalicSmCdBk", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #000000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 3.1578947368421053% 23px 0;
}
.category-products .products-list .item {
  padding: 28px 0;
}
.category-products .products-list .item .product-shop {
  width: 35.526315789473685%;
  float: left;
}
.category-products .products-list .item .product-shop h3 {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
}
.category-products .products-list .item .desc {
  font: 15px/20px "UnitedSansSmCdBd", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #6e6e6e;
}
.category-products .products-list button.utility {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.category-products .products-list .price-box {
  margin: 28px 0;
}
.category-products .products-list .swatches {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.category-products .price-box {
  text-align: center;
  *zoom: 1;
}
.category-products .price-box:before,
.category-products .price-box:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  line-height: 0;
}
.category-products .price-box:after {
  clear: both;
}
.category-products .price-box:before,
.category-products .price-box:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.category-products .price-box:after {
  clear: both;
}
.category-products .price-box .price-label {
  display: none;
}
.category-products .price-box .old-price,
.category-products .price-box .special-price {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.category-products .price-box .special-price {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.category-products .price-box .old-price {
  color: #b6b6b6;
}
.category-products .price-box .old-price .price {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #b6b6b6;
}
.category-products .price-box .special-price .price {
  color: #f89c29;
}
.category-products .product-image-wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 31.842105263157894%;
  margin-right: 2.236842105263158%;
  text-align: center;
}
.category-products .swatches {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.category-products .swatches .swatch {
  border: 1px solid #b6b6b6;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 3px 3px 0;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 31px;
}
.category-products .swatches .swatch img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

The grid system CSS (the whole CSS is pretty huge and I'm not allowed to upload that much of it on SO):

```
/** 3 column grid - based on a 960px grid system **/
.col-3-grid .products-grid .item {
  float: left;
  margin: 1.8421052631578945% 1.8421052631578945% 0 0;
  width: 31.710526315789473%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.col-3-grid .products-grid .item.last {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.col-3-grid .product-image img {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
.col-3-grid .products-grid .item .price-box {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
  /** 2 Grids - (Single Column Layouts) **/
  .col-3-grid .products-grid .item {
    min-height: 0 !important;
    float: none;
    margin: 9px 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .col-3-grid .products-grid .item.last,
  .col-3-grid .products-grid .item.last {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
/* Products grid */
.products-grid {
  *zoom: 1;
}
.products-grid:before,
.products-grid:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  line-height: 0;
}
.products-grid:after {
  clear: both;
}
.products-grid:before,
.products-grid:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.products-grid:after {
  clear: both;
}
.products-grid .item {
  float: left;
  margin: 1.8421052631578945% 1.8421052631578945% 30px 0;
  width: 31.842105263157894%;
  text-align: center;
}
.products-grid .item .product-name {
  margin: 15px 0 5px 0;
  padding: 0 8px;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You were missing a style=" on the second img-tag

Comment: With a mix of inline styles, and a complex only partially explained grid system, i think your only chance of an answer is a live link

Comment: link or simplified version of the problem via jsfiddle please.

Answer (score 0):

you can use media queries for your style according to adaptive view if your grid system is not working properly
e.g :

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .exmple{
    display: none;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet it is your borders, paddings, margins and decimal percentages..

When you use so many numbers after the decimal point, there is not much room for the border, if the browser is smaller than yours, and by mixing pixel-widths and percentages you are just making it harder for yourself.

try using the outline-property and a "simple" percentage, like so:

```
box {
  width:25%;
  margin: 1.5%;
  padding: 2.5%;
  outline 1px solid #b6b6b6;
}
```

I found [this link](http://designshack.net/articles/css/beating-borders-the-bane-of-responsive-layout/) with more info on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have a media query to clear for medium or smaller screens according to your design break-point.

Have a class like `clearElement` and add it to every third element.
add a query like this

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
.clearElement{
   clear:both;
     }
}
```